# How do I configure FFTW3 installed via HomeBrew?

Tags: homebrew, fftw

I have installed FFTW3 using HomeBrew which downloads the file located at https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/fftw-3.3.8_1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz and installs it on my system which is running on `macOS 10.14.6`. Now, the installation is fine and `gcc` is able to compile code that uses the `fttw3.h` header file.

However, there is [supposed to be](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Installation-on-Unix.html#Installation-on-Unix) a `./configure` script which I should be able to use to customise my configuration and, unfortunately, it does not exist in `/usr/local/Cellar/fftw/3.3.8_1`.

Where can I find it? How else should I configure the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build process of a Homebrew package is defined in a file called formula, which is written in Ruby.

> A formula is a package definition written in Ruby. It can be created with `brew create <URL>` where  is a zip or tarball, installed with `brew install <formula>`.

You can get the formula for `fftw` from [homebrew/core/Formula/fftw.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/fftw.rb).

And the configuration options are defined in the `args` array.

```rb
# https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/e7c8239a8a7c9b4501c4a18a4028cae82e254984/Formula/fftw.rb#L21-L30

  def install
    args = [
      "--enable-shared",
      "--disable-debug",
      "--prefix=#{prefix}",
      "--enable-threads",
      "--disable-dependency-tracking",
      "--enable-mpi",
      "--enable-openmp",
    ]
```

Download the `fftw.rb` formula file and change the configuration options. After that, install the modified formula by building it from source.

```sh
brew install --build-from-source local/path/to/modified-fftw.rb
```

#### Extended Reading

To get how to write your own formula. Check

- [Formula Cookbook](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook)
- [How to Create and Maintain a Tap](https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap)

#### FAQ

Why `brew edit fftw` is not recommended?

Homebrew is made of two parts: the `brew` command and formula repos. `fftw.rb` is a formula defined in the built-in, **local** formula repo [homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core). When you use `brew edit fftw`, you are editing the file from the local repo directly. Unless you're going to contribute to this repo, don't edit files within the homebrew-core repo directly.

Comment: I am not disagreeing, in fact, I am just trying to learn. Why do you say to download `fftw.rb` when there is a command `brew edit fftw` ? Is there some difference?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Homebrew is made of two parts: the `brew` command and the formula repos. `fftw.rb` is a formula defined in the **local** formula repo homebrew-core. When you `brew edit fftw`, you are editing the file from the local repo directly. Unless you're going to contribute to this repo, don't edit file within the homebrew-core repo directly.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for explaining. You already have my vote :-)